# select top ? * from a table - where '?' is configurable

Tags: sql, spring-jdbc

I am using spring JdbcTemplate. I have a query like this **select top ? * from table** and i am setting the value of ? from a calling method like this :

```
jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(final Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            return connection
                    .prepareStatement(**select top ? * from table**);
        }
    }, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setLong(1, 5);
        }
    },
    new ResultSetExtractor<Object>() {
        @Override
        public List<Object> extractData(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            final List<Object> objects = Lists.newArrayList();
            //assume there is correct code
            return objects;
        }
    });
```

But this is throwing me a BadSqlGrammerException : incorrect syntax near @PO.

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What values are you setting `?` to?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008. and i have set the value of ? to 5 in setValues method of PreparedStatementSetter

Comment: Anyways i got the solution, its just setting couple of attributes of jdbcTemplate as follows. jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(value);
        jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(value);

Comment: since jdbcTemplate is shared I assume jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(value); jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(value); is not thread safe...

Comment: I agree. It was a mistake to set it on jdbcTemplate(in our context it was a spring bean (singleton) and the setters were exposed, which introduced a bug in the product as it was being used at multiple places).